# Task about dice and coins

Tags: math, probability, dice, probability-theory

Set the task about dice, tried to solve, it didn’t work out. Help me please.

*Throw one dice. If 2 falls, we get 2 coins, if 3 - 3 coins, etc. to 6. If 1 falls, the game ends. How much can you earn on average per game?*

My attempt to solve - 2*1/6 + 3*1/6 + 4*1/6 + 5*1/6 + 6*1/6.
Also I thought about (2+3+4+5+6)*5/6, but i don't know if that is correct

Comment: Please provide a solution attempt.

Comment: @sooobus added)

Comment: Your first solution looks good.